# Difference between domain vs hostnames

Tags: url

I am very confused about the whole domain vs hostname thing. I tried googling, but the answers are too confusing for me, so I wanted to create a question using a specific example known to most people.

So lets take as an example atlassian's products. The URL is `atlassian.net`.
If I wanted to create my project on atlassian, URL would look like `myproject.atlassian.net`. My customer potentially wants a similar system for his website, so I need to know how to validate the names of subprojects.

So, is `myproject` a subdomain or a host?

What are naming rules, e.g. can I use underscores/dots in that part of URL?

How does routing work for such URLs? DNS resolves the top URL `atlassian.net` and then server logic serves pages for specific subproject?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most common case Hostname (e.g. localhost) is usually parameter used for internal program reference and domain name is used for external / internet reference. How domain resolve to hostname can't be summarized easily. You may see many places where both by fault were used as synonyms and so based on context you need to figure out the purpose.

Your example is not correct in context of JIRA.
"mycompany.atlassian.net" is actually your company account it might have multiple projects within it issues that are within the project got URLs like "mycompany.atlassian.net/browse/STAC-20" where STAC is the project key

It terms of how domain/sub-domain name works. There are different level of configurations and a good start for you probably might be this link:
https://uk.godaddy.com/help/what-is-a-subdomain-296

Here is short explanation in case you are referencing "Name server" hosts:
Each domain once configured needs 2-3 name servers that will know how to resolve all its subdomains, aliases usually these are provided by hosting company where we are placing our domain.
So if "mydomain.com"  might be configured with "ns1.anyhosting.com", "ns2.anyhosting.com" to serve "mydomain.com" dns requests.

In case you are the one that wants to to host "name server". It is possible by configuring "Hosts" at domain registration that have explicit IPs e.g. "ns1.mydomain.com" , "ns2.mydomain.com" and these are referred as Hosts.

Answer (score 1):

This is the exact word from my textbook:

Demonstrate by giving an example:

```
What is the hostname of the following URL? 

http://www.weather.com/summer/temperatures.html

solution: www.weather.com
```

Reason:

```
The hostname is the complete domain name, which is the characters after the scheme and 

before the path.
```

Some other definitions:

Scheme - Characters at the beginning of a URL followed by a colon ":" or a colon and double slashes "://". Common URL schemes include http, https, mailto, and file. Ex: In http://www.cdc.gov/alcohol, the scheme is "http".

Hostname - The complete domain name specified in the URL. Ex: In http://www.cdc.gov/alcohol, the hostname is "www.cdc.gov".

Path - All characters to the right of the hostname in the URL. Ex: In http://www.cdc.gov/alcohol, the path is "/alcohol".